# Flask socket-io returns different SID each request

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, request

I am trying to implement a socket app using flask-socketio that can send private messages, and one thing that I need to do is store the request.sid for each user so that I can send messages directly to that user. Although, every time the user sends a request, their request.sid changes. This is some sample code that I am using to check the users sid:

```
@socket_.on('check_requestid', namespace='/check')
def check():
    print(request.sid)
```

This is my socket init code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "Secret_Key"
#SocketIO
socket_ = SocketIO(app)
```

I am not sure what is happening and why my socket connection keeps changing its sid.

Comment: The id will be different for every different connection from the client to the server. So your "problem" is totally normal.

Comment: I am also a little bit confused by this. Any change there is some documentation on this out there?

Comment: I am sorry, I haven't found a change in documentation regarding this subject @FrankMartin. The behaviour is totally normal, and the implementation I decided to go for is to put the User in his/her own room with the id of the room being the user's id. Then, I would emit encrypted messages into that room with python that the user would decrypt in js.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, You cannot have a system like this without accounts.
You can use "pyrebase4" for user login. And the user will be able to login to their account.